# PostgreSQL : LEFT JOIN with tempory table adding extra lines

Tags: postgresql, left-join, temporary

I have a view storing water pipes references together with details on operations on the water system. I need to extract from that view the water pipes on which more than one operation were registered over the past 12 months. Here is how I proceed :

Here is the view structure and a sample of data:

```
CREATE TABLE schema.pipe (
  id INTEGER,
  code VARCHAR, 
  ope_date DATE, 
  ope_type VARCHAR(2),
  system VARCHAR(2));

INSERT INTO schema.pipe (code, ope_date, ope_type, system) VALUES
 ('0001', '2014-11-11', '01', 'EU'),
 ('0001', '2014-11-11', '03', 'EU'),
 ('0002', '2014-12-03', '03', 'EP'),
 ('0002', '2014-01-03', '03', 'EP'),
 ('0003', '2014-08-11', '01', 'EP'),
 ('0003', '2014-03-03', '03', 'EP'),
 ('0003', '2012-02-27', '03', 'EP'),
 ('0004', '2014-08-11', '01', 'UN'),
 ('0004', '2013-12-30', '03', 'UN'),
 ('0004', '2013-06-01', '03', 'UN'),
 ('0004', '2012-07-31', '03', 'UN'),
 ('0005', '2013-10-01', '03', 'EU'),
 ('0005', '2012-11-01', '03', 'EU'),
 ('0006', '2014-04-01', '01', 'UN'),
 ('0006', '2014-05-15', '01', 'UN');
```

- `code` is the pipe reference
- `ope_date` is the operation date
- `ope_type` is the operation type
- `system` is the system type

Here is the query I'm using:

```
SELECT code, ope_date FROM schema.pipe 
WHERE (NOW()::DATE - ope_date) < 365 
GROUP BY code, ope_date 
HAVING count(*) = 1 ;
```

I get this:

```
  code   |   ope_date
---------+--------------  
  0002   |   2014-12-03
  0002   |   2014-01-03
  0003   |   2014-08-11
  0003   |   2014-03-03
  0004   |   2013-12-30
  0004   |   2014-08-11
  0006   |   2014-04-01
  0006   |   2014-05-15
```

Now, I need to bring back the other columns with this selection. So I use:

```
WITH temptable AS (
    SELECT code, ope_date FROM schema.pipe WHERE (NOW()::DATE - ope_date) < 365 GROUP BY code, ope_date HAVING count(*) = 1)

SELECT DISTINCT a.code, a.ope_date, b.ope_type, b.system FROM temptable a LEFT JOIN schema.pipe b on a.code = b.code ;
```

I get this, which is too many lines (I need 8 lines and I get 12):

```
  code  |  ope_date    |  ope_type  |  system
 -------+--------------+------------+---------
  0002  |  2014-01-03  |  03        |  EP
  0002  |  2014-12-03  |  03        |  EP
  0003  |  2014-03-03  |  01        |  EP
  0003  |  2014-03-03  |  03        |  EP
  0003  |  2014-08-11  |  01        |  EP
  0003  |  2014-08-11  |  03        |  EP
  0004  |  2013-12-30  |  01        |  UN
  0004  |  2013-12-30  |  03        |  UN
  0004  |  2014-08-11  |  01        |  UN
  0004  |  2014-08-11  |  03        |  UN
  0006  |  2014-04-01  |  01        |  UN
  0006  |  2014-05-15  |  01        |  UN
```

So here comes my question: how can I get just the lines matching my selection?

Many thanks in advance.

EDIT :

What I need is:

```
  code   | ope_date    | ope_type  | system
---------+-------------+-----------+---------  
  0002   | 2014-12-03  | 03        | EP
  0002   | 2014-01-03  | 03        | EP
  0003   | 2014-08-11  | 01        | EP
  0003   | 2014-03-03  | 03        | EP
  0004   | 2013-12-30  | 03        | UN
  0004   | 2014-08-11  | 01        | UN
  0006   | 2014-04-01  | 01        | UN
  0006   | 2014-05-15  | 01        | UN
```

Comment: they are matching your selection. you've two rows, with different `ope_type`, with `code` 0003 and code 0004, vs a single one for codes 0002 and code 0006.

Comment: I have just edited my post (at the bottom). What I need is the result of my fisrt query (8 lines) together with the matching columns. For instance, why do I get `0003 | 2014-03-03 | 01 | EP` in the 12 lines query result? This line is not in the `pipe` table...

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: Thanks, excellent site... I have posted an answer with a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've found myself a solution that consists in using both `code` and `ope_date` columns to join the tables (not just `code`):

```
WITH temptable AS (
    SELECT code, ope_date FROM schema.pipe WHERE (NOW()::DATE - ope_date) < 365 GROUP BY code, ope_date HAVING count(*) = 1)

SELECT DISTINCT a.code, a.ope_date, b.ope_type, b.system FROM temptable a, schema.pipe b WHERE a.code = b.code AND a.ope_date = b.ope_date;
```

Any comment on this solution?

Comment: It's more readable with `from ... join ... on ... and ...`. (You can join on multiple columns.)